# Linux Shell Script execute without save to temporary variable

Tags: linux, bash

If I want to execute a command with variables in it, I always have to store the string first in a variable and then can execute it...

Example:

```
path_fasta="/home/xxx/yyy/zzz/qqq/"
name_fasta="CTA_Mix_DNA.fna"
path_outp"/some/Path/"

temp='find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name '$name_fasta' -not -name letsgo.sh -delete'
$temp

temp=$path_mothur'mothur #set.dir(output='$path_outp');summary.seqs(fasta='$path_fasta''$name_fasta')'
$temp
```

How do I do this directly **without storing it first in temp**? Must be easy, but did not find a solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
temp='find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name '$name_fasta' -not -name letsgo.sh -delete'
$temp
```

...just use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name "$name_fasta" -not -name letsgo.sh -delete
```

Comment: Why the literal single quotes? If the value of the variable contains a single quote, you're hosed. Why not just double quote the variable?